# how to remove parentheses for negative number in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove parentheses for negative numbers in excel, but I have so far been unable to remove them successfully

I tried below code:

```
sheet1.UsedRange.Select
sheet1.Range("A:XFD").NumberFormat = "0.00"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True
```

but it only works after doing `TextToColumns` manually. I need a more general solution, as I don't always know which rows have numbers.

Comment: I just need to check before I post my answer, are you classing paretheses as just brackets "()" or is it any length of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has to do with the format of the cell.   Right-Click cell > Format > (Select Number or Currency) change how you want the negative number to look. ... or if you want to do it in VBA, this will change the negative values to red:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
```

This will change it back to ():

```
Range("A1").Style = "Currency"
```

or this:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"
```

Comment: it will change after i do texttocoulmns

Comment: Try setting the style to something other than currency.